# Правильный url для seo

Tags: url, seo, react-router

На данный момент первая страница сайта с продукцией имеет вид: https://site.ru/produkcija/1, где 1, соответственно, номер страницы. Сайт написан на React, используется react-router. Этот номер извлекается с помощью useParams() для организации пагинации. Нужно ли переделать именно с точки зрения seo принцип формирования url, чтобы первая страница с продукцией имела url https://site.ru/produkcija?

Comment: я нашла статью https://habr.com/ru/articles/713666/, там есть пункты #3 Цифры в URL-адресах могут быть вредными и #4 Слишком большое количество слешей в URL может повредить рейтингу. В принципе вообще можно всю продукцию выводить на одной странице, без пагинации. Так будет лучше для seo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Слишком много слешей — либо когда вложенность большая  https://site.ru/produkcija/categoriya1/podgategoriya1/l3categoriya/1, либо когда у сайта не закртыты дырки дубльстраниц по типу https://site.ru////produkcija////1///
2. URL-адресах — это старые извращения яндекса, которые не убрали, и судя по всему никогда не уберут. С Google таких проблем не возникает. Но лучше всего, когда адрес идет ЧПУ (человеку понятный url) по типу https://site.ru/produkcija/myach-detskiy-naduvnoy. Но только такие url удасться поддерживать пока товарка не широкого ассортимента.